# Escape Aspas Simples e duplas do text área mesmo dando crlt + V

Tags: javascript, jquery

// Desejo apenas não deixar digitar as aspas simples e aspas duplas

```
$('#bot').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte `Regex`:

```js
$('#bot').on('keypress', function (e) {

    if (!/['"]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))) {
        return;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Digite algo: <textarea id='bot'></textarea>
```

Comment: E a questão do CTRL+V?

Answer (score 14):

O problema de `keypress` é que não vai reconhecer se os dados vierem de outras origens, ou seja, não vai funcionar com Ctrl+V ou com o clique direito do mouse.

Eu recomendo primeiramente usar `.on('input')` e ao invés de ter que ficar checando caractere por caractere:

```
String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode)
```

Pode simplesmente usar `.replace` no `.val()` ou `.value`

Assim:

```js
$('#bot').on('input', function (e) {
   this.value = this.value.replace(/['"]/g, "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Digite algo: <textarea id='bot'></textarea>
```

Dessa forma vai funcionar quando digitar e quando usar Ctrl+V, não vai ficar precisando adicionar todos eventos, como:

- `.on('keypress')`
- `.on('paste')`

Comment: foi mais rápido que eu, +1 boa :)

Comment: @Henrique se tiver outra sugestão, diferente é claro, que também resolva não existe em responder :D pode garantir uns pontinhos e ainda ajudar muitos usuários.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento resolve "***de forma bem mais simples***" mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma, só verificando as aspas e aspas simples com um if simples:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#bot').keypress(function (e) {      
      var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
      if (str == '"' || str == "'") {
          return false;
      }
      return true; 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="bot"></textarea>
```

Eu não sei qual é a sua preocupação com as aspas, mas você também pode substituir elas por `HTML Entities`, da seguinte forma:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#bot').keypress(function (e) {      
      var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
      if (str == '"') {
        $(this).html($(this).val() + '&quot;');
          return false;
      }
      if (str == "'") {
        $(this).html($(this).val() + '&apos;');
          return false;
      }
      return true; 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="bot"></textarea>
```

Assim o usuário poderá utilizar as aspas e você vai ter o `HTML Entities` no lugar das aspas por trás.

Comment: E a questão do CTRL+V?

Comment: É eu não pensei nisso